# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=1-\frac{1}{m+1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I know $\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=1-\frac{1}{m+1}= H_mH_{m+1}$,   for $H_m$ the harmonic sum.

I tried many ways to prove it like this

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(\frac{1}{k(k+1)} + \frac{1}{m+1}\right)=1  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \left(\frac{1}{k(k+1)}+\frac{1}{m+1} + \frac{1}{m(m+1)}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \left(\frac{1}{k(k+1)} + \frac{m^2 + 1}{m(m+1)}\right) = 1.$$

**My questions are:**

1. Could anyone give me any hints to calculate it, but not the solution, please?

   **Thanks! $\Rightarrow$ it's OK I solved the exercise :) !!**
2. Is the calculation, I wrote above here, correct? Or not?

Comment: Your scribbling makes no sense to me. Why you want to sum $1/(m+1)$? If you don't know what you want to prove, how anybody can help you? Anyway please write your questions in mathjax (see help page).

Comment: @Karl Try to read now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $\frac1{k(k+1)}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}$.

Comment: this hint was helpful for me. I solved the problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Induction would probably work out here too. For $m=1$ we have $$\frac1{1\cdot 2} = 1-\frac12.$$ Then for $m=2$ we have $$\frac{1}{1\cdot2} + \frac{1}{2\cdot 3} = \left(1 - \frac12\right) + \frac1{2\cdot3}=1-\frac{3-1}{2\cdot 3}=1-\frac{1}{3}.$$

Try to do this in general.

Comment: this hint was  helpful for me. I solved the problem. Thank you!! While I was thinking how to do the exercise I didn't considered the induction, because I thought so the ex. became a bit heavy for me.

Comment: I am glad you found our hints helpful. :)